# MPMoviePlayerController from a UITableview

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

HI I have a UITableview , when a user clicks on a particular cell i play the video using the MPmovieplayercontroller , the view plays correctly and there is a done button on top . when i click on the done button i need to come back to the main view controller wchih has the UIble view. Please see the code below and suggest me what can be done.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *surl = [videoSelected valueForKey:@"video_path"];

    NSLog(@"Video :%@",surl);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/MyWorks/files/videos/hit.mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
    [[player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  // frame must match parent view
    [self.view addSubview: [player view]];
    [player play];

    [msg release];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but try

```
[player.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[player.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTarget:player.view];
```

The code just sets the right navigation item's selector to remove the view from it's superview.

P.S You might wanna add an animation, as the deletion of the superview animation is rough.

Comment: It says "Property navigationItem cannot be found on object MPMovieplayercontroller"

Comment: Try `player.navigationController.navigationItem`